# How to set a default value on a boolean parameter with an expression in SSRS 2008?

Tags: ssrs-2008, bids

I am currently converting an inventory report from a web application into an SSRS report. I am trying to get the same functionality, but I am having trouble setting the default value of a boolean parameter based on the value of a previously selected parameter. The boolean parameter allows the user to search inventory for on hand product, true, or all product, false, if they are searching for back ordered products I want it to default, otherwise true. I am using an expression to determine with value to default to.

```
=iif(Parameters!Type.Value="Back Order",false,true)
```

When I run the report it has both true and false grayed out and neither is selected. I am trying to avoid using a multi-select drop down, but I fear I may need to to get the functionality I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did You try put false and true under " (backquote).
Are you sure that value of Type parameter is "Black Order" , maybe this is display member (label) and value is  different.
Try setting some stupid condition in IIF to see do you get results as needed =iif(1=1,true,false)

Comment: I have tried iif(1=1,true,false), it appears that it's not possible with an iif(). I was just hoping there was some other way that I was unaware of.
I am checking for the correct value, and I tried true and false in quotes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as another way:

`=Switch(Parameters!Type.Value = "Back Order", True, Parameters!Type.Value <> "Back Order", False)`

---

- I notice in your `IIf()` statement that you are attempting to assign the boolean `False` to the True output argument of the function, and vice versa, so you could also try...

  - `=IIf(Parameters!Type.Value <> "Back Order", True, False)`
  - Putting True and False in quotes will make the VB processing think they are of data-type `String`, so **don't** try that.